# JSCover - Excluding coverage files

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube-5.0, jscoverage

Currently trying to get JSCover to exclude js files that are used as libraries. I have a set of ant scripts below which will

1. start the JSCover server
2. Run & Generate Json report
3. Stop the server

Finally, i have a shell command to convert the Json file to LCov so that i can use it with sonarqube. I also get coverage in jscoverage.html but it includes every file under web/ which is something i do not want. Image below

[image]

Ant scripts below:

```
    <target name="jstest-start">
    <java jar=".../JSCover.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
        <arg value="-ws"/>
        <arg value="--report-dir=coverage"/>
        <arg value="--document-root=web"/>
        <arg value="--port=8082"/>

        <!-- Aim is to exclude folder js under web/ as it contains libraries, not source code. Currently does not work -->
        <arg value="--no-instrument=web/js/"/>
        <arg value="--no-instrument=js/"/>
    </java>

    <waitfor maxwait="5" maxwaitunit="second" checkevery="250" checkeveryunit="millisecond" timeoutproperty="failed">
        <http url="http://localhost:8082/jscoverage.html"/>
    </waitfor>
    <fail if="failed"/>

</target>

<target name="jstest-run">
    <exec dir="/usr/local/CI/phantomjs/bin/" executable="phantomjs" failonerror="true">
        <arg line=".../run-jscover-qunit.js http://localhost:8082/index.html"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="jstest-stop">
    <get src="http://localhost:8082/stop" dest="stop.txt" />
</target>

<target name="jstest" description="Run javascript tests">
    <antcall target="jstest-start"/>
    <antcall target="jstest-run"/>
    <antcall target="jstest-stop"/>
</target>
```

My folder structure is:

[image]

And finally, my sonar standalone analysis settings:

[image]

So, what seems to be happening is that JSCover is recursively reading for all js files and i cannot prevent that from sonar or ant.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved my own issue by correcting the shell command which generates an LCOV report.

```
java -cp JSCover.jar  jscover.report.Main --format=LCOV  /usr/local/CI/jenkins/workspace/PhantomJS/coverage/phantom/ /usr/local/CI/jenkins/workspace/PhantomJS/web/
```

Prior to this, the SRC-DIR and REPORT-DIR were the same which was an error on my part. As far as i can understand, SRC-DIR should point to the source folder and REPORT-DIR should point to where the lcov file exists.

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

```
<arg value="--no-instrument=/js/"/>
```

should work, and to remove the test itself,

```
<arg value="--no-instrument=/test/"/>
```

The paths are as seen by the web-server, so the 'web' prefix in:

```
<arg value="--no-instrument=web/js/"/>
```

has no effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried literally every combination i could imagine, including your first suggestion, which should work but it doesn't. 

I have ensured that the coverage folder is recreated upon every build but JSCover still includes every js file within all subfolders under the web folder